# Nutch crawl command

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

For Nutch 2.2.1, I am aware of two crawl commands - bin/nutch (step by step), bin/crawl (all in one)

I know how to specify a crawl ID for `bin/crawl` command. Similarly, how to specify a crawl ID for `bin/nutch` command?

The reason I am asking is, I ran a large crawl job using `all-in-one crawl command "bin/crawl"` specifying a crawl ID, it broke while indexing in Solr for 9th crawl iteration. Now, I just want to run one step `"bin/nutch solrindex"` command for just that interrupted 9th iteration to complete the solr indexing. How should I specify crawlID in "`bin/nutch solrindex`" command? What is the syntax?

I have all the crawl data stored in a HBase table "webpage_test"

Answer (score 1):

You can run bin/nutch solrindex and pass the crawl and segments folders in the parameters.

Nutch will index all documents but will not create duplicates as it will use the ID field to determine if they have already been inserted.